# Laravel advanced where not working in Lumen

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, lumen, lumen-5.2

I use Laravel advanced wheres in Lumen for a query in MongoDB and i use jenssegers/laravel-mongodb package for Lumen and my query is :

```
$time_5_min_ago = Carbon::now()->subMinute(5);
$time_10_min_ago = Carbon::now()->subMinute(10);
$time_15_min_ago = Carbon::now()->subMinute(15);

return Order::whereBetween('source_longitude', [$minLon_try_one, $maxLon_try_one])
    ->whereBetween('source_latitude',[$minLat_try_one,$maxLat_try_one])
    ->where('status','=','suspend')
    ->where('created_at','<=',$time_5_min_ago)
    ->where('created_at','>=',$time_10_min_ago)
    ->orWhere(function($query) use ($maxLat_try_two,$minLat_try_two,$maxLon_try_two,$minLon_try_two,$time_10_min_ago,$time_15_min_ago)
    {
        $query->whereBetween('source_longitude', [$minLon_try_two, $maxLon_try_two])
        ->whereBetween('source_latitude',[$minLat_try_two,$maxLat_try_two])
        ->where('status','=','suspend')
        ->where('created_at','<=',$time_10_min_ago)
        ->where('created_at','>=',$time_15_min_ago);
    }
    )->get();
```

But when i run this query, i got no result and i don't know how fix it?

Comment: Maybe no result is simply the result of your query? If you get no error there is nothing wrong with the code. Try building up the query slowly, step by step.

Comment: But I Got result when remove orWhere function query.

Comment: I mean the first part of query is not dependent with orWhere function query. So why not show result

Comment: Please help me friends

Comment: Anybody know to help me

Comment: And when you run both queries individually they work? Could you try to add a `->toSql()` and show us what query is generated?

Comment: i got `"data": "select * from \"orders\" where \"source_longitude\" between ? and ? and \"source_latitude\" between ? and ? and \"status\" = ? and \"created_at\" <= ? and \"created_at\" >= ? or (\"source_longitude\" between ? and ? and \"source_latitude\" between ? and ? and \"status\" = ? and \"created_at\" <= ? and \"created_at\" >= ?)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution . This works :

```
    $time_5_min_ago = Carbon::now()->subMinute(5);
    $time_10_min_ago = Carbon::now()->subMinute(10);
    $time_15_min_ago = Carbon::now()->subMinute(15);
    $time_20_min_ago = Carbon::now()->subMinute(20);

    return Order::where(function ($query)  use ($maxLat_try_one,$minLat_try_one,$maxLon_try_one,$minLon_try_one,$time_5_min_ago,$time_10_min_ago) {
        $query->whereBetween('source_longitude', [$minLon_try_one, $maxLon_try_one])
            ->whereBetween('source_latitude', [$minLat_try_one,$maxLat_try_one])
            ->where('status', '=', 'pending')
            ->where('created_at', '<', $time_5_min_ago)
            ->where('created_at', '>=', $time_10_min_ago);
    })->orWhere(function ($query)  use ($maxLat_try_two,$minLat_try_two,$maxLon_try_two,$minLon_try_two,$time_10_min_ago,$time_15_min_ago) {
        $query->whereBetween('source_longitude', [$minLon_try_two, $maxLon_try_two])
            ->whereBetween('source_latitude', [$minLat_try_two,$maxLat_try_two])
            ->where('status', '=', 'pending')
            ->where('created_at', '<', $time_10_min_ago)
            ->where('created_at', '>=', $time_15_min_ago);
    })->orWhere(function ($query)  use ($maxLat_try_three,$minLat_try_three,$maxLon_try_three,$minLon_try_three,$time_15_min_ago,$time_20_min_ago) {
        $query->whereBetween('source_longitude', [$minLon_try_three, $maxLon_try_three])
            ->whereBetween('source_latitude', [$minLat_try_three,$maxLat_try_three])
            ->where('status', '=', 'pending')
            ->where('created_at', '<', $time_15_min_ago)
            ->where('created_at', '>=', $time_20_min_ago);
    })->get($fields);
```